# Hyperledger Fabric with Raft Protocol: How are transactions packaged into Blocks?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, raft

So I do understand the concept of the Raft Protocol.
But I struggle with it in the use case of a Hyperledger Fabric Ordering Service.

**What I understand so far:**
When a transaction is proposed and endorsed by peers the application forwards it to the ordering service.
The Raft Leader-Node receives this transaction and writes it to his Log then sends it to his Follower-Nodes that also update their Logs.

**What I don't understand:**

- Where and how are the blocks created?
- Do all Nodes create a Block and check if a majority has the same?

I read somewhere that a Blockcutter-method is invoked by the Leader and the resulting Block is then proposed to the local Raft Finite State Machine (what is this?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too wasteful to do a consensus round for each transaction. Instead, the Raft leader aggregates several transactions into a batch, and then creates a block from that batch, using a block cutter object.

Then, the Raft leader initiates a consensus round to make the block be replicated to all followers via the Raft protocol.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand thank you! It really makes sense to only replicate the blocks and not single transactions, that can easily send again by the application in case it does not get a validation answer from the peers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question: when a node is follower, it only received and save block from leader, leader is only node can create block?

Comment: That is correct, only the leader in Raft creates the block, but the block is sent not-signed and each follower signs the block itself